# How to input 3 integers in one line

Tags: java

Hello can I input 3 integers in one line in java?

im writing time converter

I want to input hh:mm:ss with : as separator for int hh, mm, ss

this is my code with 3 lines input

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int hh = in.nextInt();
    int mm = in.nextInt();
    int ss = in.nextInt();
    int result;
    result = (hh*3600)+(mm*60)+(ss);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *"I haven't tried anything yet"*

Comment: i mean i tried with 3 lines input, but i want to make it only in one line and i have no idea what i suppose to write to create a separator

Comment: Look up how to split strings.

Answer (score 2):

In java, input is always in terms of String. Hence you will need to parse it to Integers after reading.
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Make use of split() method with ":" as a separator. 
Then make use of Integer wrapper class to convert in to int data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string as input and use "**:**" as separator and the parse string to int

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = in.nextLine().split(":");
        int hh = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
        int mm = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
        int ss = Integer.parseInt(input[2]);
        int result;
        result = (hh * 3600) + (mm * 60) + (ss);
        System.out.println(result);
      }
```